# how to change the data in the plain text according to the response coming in json data in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

im getting json data in the response as it is coming from response.but i need to change the data like this if  0: registered, 1: connected, 2: disconnected, 3: busy in the plain text. im able to show the data as it is coming in response,  but i need to modify according to the value getting in the response.
conditions

```
0: registered, 1: connected, 2: disconnected, 3: busy
```

op - status is- 3

desired op- status busy

sample json data from api

```
"status":3
```

code

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" align="center">

     <h2>status is-  {{statusValues[names.status]}}</h2>

        </div>

       <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('url', {
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic a2VybmVsc3B==' }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.data;
                $scope.statusValues={
                    '0' : 'registered',
                    '1' : 'connected',
                    '2': 'disconnected',
                    '3':'busy'
                };


            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Modify what? What is expected result? What does response look like also?

Comment: status is acive/inactive according to 1 or 0

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so we can understand what status you are even talking about. Are you saying `names.status` would have value of `1` or `0`?

Comment: names.status already coming in 1 or 0 , based on that i need to show status is active or inactive

Comment: *"need to show status is active or inactive"* is not what you wrote in the update with different values

Comment: Also need to learn to write full and comprehensive sentences that fully explain your issue...even if you have to use a translation service to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not entirely clear what you are asking but I thing you want:

```
<h2>status is-  {{names.status ? 'Active' :'Inactive'}}</h2>
```

This is a javascript ternary and will render the word "Active" when status is truthy (==1) and "Inactive" when it is falsy (==0)

---

Based on update perhaps you want something like:

```
$scope.statusValues={
   '0' : 'registered',
   '1' : 'connected',
    ....
   '3' : 'busy'
}
```

Then in view:

```
<h2>status is-  {{statusValues[names.status]}}</h2>
```

Comment: 0: registered,
 1: connected,
 2: disconnected,
 3: busy

Comment: Supply all the proper details in the question. You only mentioned `1` or `0`. People can't help properly when you aren't complete and concise

Comment: See update...your comments are conflicting with updates making this even more confusing

Comment: i modified my code, still im not getting the desired op. its showing blank,updated my code in question.can u tell me where i did mistake

Comment: Not until you do what was originally asked and provide a data sample, not some text that is similar

Comment: i tried my level best to make you understand my requirement , can you check my code once ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132034/discussion-between-swapna-and-charlietfl).